# What's wrong with this simplified Bell experiment?

Tags: qiskit, bell-experiment

This code is supposed to be sending two oppositely-entangled qubits to two measuring devices. Each measuring device chooses one of three angles at random. with the three angles being 120 degrees apart. The last statement prints the probability that the two measuring devices disagree. The theoretical value for that probability is 0.5, but this code gives me widely-varying values (usually between 0.3 and 0.7).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


def get_circuit(angle_left, angle_right):
    circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
    circ.h(0)
    circ.cnot(0, 1)
    circ.x(1)
    circ.barrier()
    circ.ry(angle_left, 0)
    circ.ry(angle_right, 1)
    circ.measure_all()
    display(circ.draw('latex'))
    return circ


# In[2]:


from math import pi

northwest = pi / 6
southwest = 5 * pi / 6
east = 9 * pi / 6
directions = [northwest, southwest, east]

nine_circs = []
for dir_left in directions:
    for dir_right in directions:
        nine_circs.append(get_circuit(dir_left, dir_right))


# In[3]:


import random

circ_counts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
random_circs = []
for i in range(1000):
    circ_number = random.randint(0, 8)
    random_circs.append(nine_circs[circ_number])
    circ_counts[circ_number] += 1
print('Circuit counts: ', end='')
print(circ_counts)
print('nw nw | nw se | nw e | se nw | se se | se e | e nw | e sw | e e')


# In[4]:


from qiskit import IBMQ, transpile
from qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed import IBMQJobManager

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
device = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
# Use a quantum computer with at least two qubits

ranndom_circs = transpile(random_circs, backend=device)
manager = IBMQJobManager()
job = manager.run(random_circs, backend=device, shots=1)
result = job.results()
#print('finished')


# In[ ]:


print('started')
disagree = 0
total = 0
for circ in random_circs:
    output = result.get_counts(circ)
    total += 1
    # print(output, end=' ')
    if '01' in output or '10' in output:   # if output[0] != output[1]:
        disagree += 1
    if disagree % 50 == 0:
        print(disagree / total)
print('\nProbability of disagreement: '
      + str(disagree / len(random_circs)))


# In[ ]:
```

Here's an earlier version of the code that seems to work just fine. The only trouble is, the earlier version doesn't do random selection of circuits:

````
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[2]:


from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


def get_circuit(angle_left, angle_right):
    circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
    circ.h(0)
    circ.cnot(0, 1)
    circ.x(1)
    circ.ry(angle_left, 0)
    circ.ry(angle_right, 1)
    circ.measure_all()
    display(circ.draw('latex'))
    return circ


# In[3]:


from math import pi

northwest = pi / 6
southwest = 5 * pi / 6
east = 9 * pi / 6
directions = [northwest, southwest, east]

circuits = []
for dir_left in directions:
    for dir_right in directions:
        circuits.append(get_circuit(dir_left, dir_right))


# In[4]:


from qiskit import IBMQ, execute
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
device = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
# Use a quantum computer with at least two qubits

shots = 100
job =    execute(circuits, backend=device, shots=shots, memory=True)
result = job.result()



# In[5]:


disagree = 0
for circ in circuits:
    memory = result.get_memory(circ)
    for element in memory:
        if element[0] != element[1]:
            disagree += 1
    # print(memory)
print('\nProbability of disagreement: '
      + str(disagree / (9 * shots)))
```
````

Comment: Maybe you should describe what it's supposed to do and what it's not doing?

Comment: It's supposed to be sending two oppositely-entangled qubits to two measuring devices. Each measuring device chooses one of three angles at random. with the three angles being 120 degrees apart. The last statement prints the probability that the two measuring devices disagree. The theoretical value for that probability is 0.5, but this code gives me widely-varying values (usually between 0.3 and 0.7).

Answer (score 1):

One issue could be that you are not taking very many samples.  You have 1000 random circuits, but you seem to only simulate one shot from each of them.  Since there are 9 possible settings, this means you are, for each setting, only running 1000/9 or about 111 shots per setting.  With this few settings per shot you will see statistical fluctuations of around 10%.  Combining those when looking at the disagreement you calculate will give you something that fluctuates like you say.

I would suggest rewriting the code so that it does each measurement setting an equal amount of times, and then use the shots parameter to be something much larger to see statistical significance.  Or just increase your 1000 random circuits to say 100000 to get more like one percent error per setting.

Comment: In fact, my first try at this code did exactly what you suggest. But I did it with only 1000 shots and it works just fine. I'm adding that first-try code to my original question (above). I revised the first-try code because I felt guilty about not doing random selections of measurement orientations.